# How can I get jQuery to add a placeholder before the image is faded?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this to fade elements on my page:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#holder').delay(650).fadeIn(1000);
         $('#sidepanelHolder').delay(650).fadeIn(1000);
         $('#bottomHolder').delay(1200).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

And this CSS to add a placeholder so the area isn't invisible then visible, moving whatever is under it:

```
.nope {
    display: none;  
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<article class="featureBottom">
     <div id="bottomHolder" class="nope">
       <img src="/images/features/one.jpg" width="100%" alt="" />
      </div>
</article>
```

I am leaving the `id` undefined, just using it for jQuery...

The fading images for `#holder` and `#sidePanelHolder` work fine, but the `#bottomHolder` is not working:

```
.featureBottom {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block; 
}
```

Is there an easier way to add placeholders that are the height and width of whatver you are fading, so that it fades without going from `hidden` to `block`, moving elements down the page underneath the faders.

Hope that makes sense :-)

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

This is the page before the image fades:

[image: holder]

The placeholder is not present here. The S's and the footer (change of background texture) are close together.

Then the image loads:

[image: holder with image]

Pushing the footer down, the `auto` height & width for `.nope` is not obeyed here, like they are for my other two faders on the same page: `holder` and `sidepanelHolder`.

Comment: So this is really about the footer then? You want it to stay at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback or several callbacks. That way the others don't start their fadeIn until the first is done. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113744/jquery-fade-in-callback-not-waiting).

A call back changes your code to look like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#holder').delay(650).fadeIn(1000,function(){
             $('#sidepanelHolder').delay(650).fadeIn(1000);
             $('#bottomHolder').delay(1200).fadeIn(1000);
         });         
});
```

If you want your footer to stay at the bottom of the page the entire time, try this trick from CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Thx. The content under `#bottomHolder` still moves until it begins its fade :-(

Comment: are the delays in there to slow down the fadeIn? can I remove?

Comment: they are, but remove! :-)

Comment: OK I'm trying to understand what you need, but I'm not sure I get it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by "moves"?

Comment: I do have other images that do obey the `.nope` css rule however, it is strange how on this one, the placeholder doesn't load the image's size before it is faded....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138684/discussion-between-garek007-and-davvv).