# jQuery .fadeIn occurs at same time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to make a banner using jQuery, I used 4 images at the same position that start with display: none and then I tried to fade in the first image then fade it out and so on for the 4 of them.

That's the code I have built:

```
    $('.aaa').fadeIn(length);
    $('.aaa').fadeOut(length);
    $('.aab').fadeIn(length);
    $('.aab').fadeOut(length);
    $('.aac').fadeIn(length);
    $('.aac').fadeOut(length);
    $('.aad').fadeIn(length);
    $('.aad').fadeOut(length);
```

It did fade out and in but all of the images were fading at the same time which looked really weird, does somebody know how to make them fade separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery fade in callback not waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113744/jquery-fade-in-callback-not-waiting)

Comment: You could try something like this that follows your current markup (I think at least). But to be honest, it feels a little dirty to next the promises like this.  https://jsfiddle.net/ko48e98u/2/

Answer (score 0):

if they are in order and share a class you can loop through each one displaying it then fading it out

```
var imgs = $('.common').toArray();

 function disp_next() {
   $(imgs.shift()).fadeIn()
   .delay(1000)
   .fadeOut(function(){
     if(imgs.length !== 0) {
         disp_next();
     }
  })
 }

disp_next();
```

if they can't share a common class or any other way to get them all in one jQuery selector, you can use the callback functions of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

```
$('.aaa').fadeIn(function(){
    $('.aaa').fadeOut(function(){
        $('.aab').fadeIn(function(){
            $('.aab').fadeOut();
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: *Note: The first parameter for fadeIn/fadeOut can also be an integer indicating the fade duration in milliseconds. 400ms is default. The callback will fire when the fade is complete. The following would be a 400ms fadein, a 4 second pause, then a 400ms fadeout.
 $('.aaa').fadeIn(400,function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
          $('.aaa').fadeOut();
     }, 4000);
});